# Archivos JAVA con icono de JConsole

Tags: windows

Estaba buscando varios IDE para empezar a programar e instalé muchos programas como code::block, visual studio, eclipse, etc y desde ese día comenzaron a salirme en todos mis archivos java el icono de un "Pinguino" que por lo que leí es imagen de JConsole (no estoy seguro si la culpa es de los IDE que descargué o de otra cosa)

Nunca he instalado Jconsole y tengo sistema operativo Windows

[image: Imagen de mis archivos java]

cada archivo Java que descargo tiene esa imagen, no estoy seguro si es un virus o cómo puedo desinstalarlo.

Comment: Los SO (Windows por ejemplo) te permiten asociar programas a ciertos tipos de fichero. Seguramente le has asignado a la extensión .java el JConsole por defecto. Esto es más tema de configuración de windows que de Java, te recomiendo que al menos incluyas la etiqueta correcta. Además, saber qué sistema operativo estás corriendo ayudaría mucho.

Comment: @Benito-B lo siento por lo de la etiqueta! Ya está editada. Entiendo lo de asociar ciertos programas a ciertos ficheros, pero para eso no sería necesario por lo menos tener el JConsole instalado? Jamas había escuchado sobre ese programa y mucho menos lo había instalado, por eso tuve tanto problema al encontrar de donde era ese pinguino!

Comment: Mismo problema, ya encontraste una solución? o tengo que vivir con el pingüino?